# Two classes give the output different on same code while locating a resource in java

Tags: java, resources, eclipse-rcp

i have two classes as

```
public class CsvReaderExample { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {               
    String file=CsvReaderExample.class.getResource("/saralbitta/common/db/DateNepali.csv").getFile();
```

Next class is

```
 public class LoanIssueView extends ViewPart {
    public LoanIssueView() {    
            }
            @Override
   public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
   String file=LoanIssueView.class.getResource("/saralbitta/common/db/DateNepali.csv").getFile();
```

When i print `file` in both the classes i am so surprised that in one class i get the outPut as below in first case

```
 /E:/myskbbl/saralbitta/bin/saralbitta/common/db/DateNepali.csv
```

similarly in second case i get outPut as

```
/saralbitta/common/db/DateNepali.csv
```

Why the two classes with same code give different output. i am getting fileNotFoundException in second case as i need the output like in first case. How can i obtain the like the output like first case in the second one?

Comment: Do you have access to the second class?

Comment: @RomanC both are independent class. they do not have link to eachother.

Comment: Why is the code attempting to establish a `File` for an application resource?  If it is an embedded resource, it needs to be accessed by URL.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i have put the csv file in my project and i required to know its url of its in the drive.

Comment: Does the app. attempt to **write** to the CSV, or is it read only?

Comment: @AndrewThompson have only read the csv from the location i obtained.

Comment: Is this running in a Web Application?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman no they are desktop application. is there any way i get the output like in the first case for second one.

Comment: *"have only read the csv"*  Then *read it using URL!*  Forget the file, if the path returned is not `null` or throws an exception, I would not even look at the path.

Comment: @Dinupkandel What do you mean "link to each other"?

Answer (score 0):

Are the classes CsvReaderExample and LoanIssueView contained in different bundles/plugins? Each bundle has its own classpath and cannot see the classes of other bundles, unless you allow it. Interbundle dependencies are declared in the Manifest.

Edit: Ok then it's clear. In the first case OSGi is not started, so it's a normal Java application. In the second case OSGi is started and each bundle gets its own classloader. I would try to request the Resource from the bundle. Use the getResource() method there http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29. You can acquire a bundle reference from the **BundleContext**. You get the **BundleContext** from the **BundleActivator** start() method http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html#start%28org.osgi.framework.BundleContext%29. Note that the URL you acquire, is not a File URL. Use **FileLocator** to convert the URL to a File URL http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FFileLocator.html.

Comment: They are in the same package and in the same project?

Comment: willing in first case i just run a single class as it static void main. the next case i run in the application that's why i am be getting different result. so is there any way to get url in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Where are these programs executed from? When the resource is looked up, there is an algorithm by which the absolute name is determined. It also depends on the class loader. Probably that is why you see different results.

Comment: may be you are write. i just run a single class in case static void main() in first case but next one is i have the run the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

It should be related to the difference in classpath setting. Check the classpath setting for both apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for both [`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [`findResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource%28java.lang.String%29)

In first case, `getResource()` is returning you the file string. But in second case, somehow the `getResource()` is not able to find the path and tries to invoke `findResource()` method, as stated in it's documentation:

[`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) :

> This method will first search the parent class loader for the resource; 
>   if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in to the 
>   virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will invoke 
>   findResource(String) to find the resource.

Probably this might be reason here for different return strings, as different methods might be getting called depending on the flow.